# PowerShell to remove all AD attributes when matching the specific string?

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, office365, exchange-server

I wanted to remove smtp:*@olddomain.com in all of my users, but somehow the cmdlet does not take the wild card to loop through the attributes.

Script:

```
$DefaultDomain = 'NewCompany.onmicrosoft.com'
$OldDomain = 'olddomain.com'

$DistributionGroups = Import-Csv -LiteralPath C:\Source-DL.csv
$DistributionGroups | ForEach-Object { 
                            Write-Host "Set DL: $($_.DisplayName) into [$($_.Alias+"@"+$DefaultDomain)]" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                            Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $_.Alias -WindowsEmailAddress $($_.Alias+"@"+$DefaultDomain) -Emailaddresses @{remove="$($_.Alias)@$OldDomain"}
                     }
```

The environment is not on-premise AD hence I can only access the Azure AD or Exchange Online cmdlet.

Comment: For multi-valued AD attributes, you need to specify an exact text match. So something like `Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $DG.Alias | select -expand EmailAddresses | where {$_ -like "SMTP:$($DG.Alias)@$oldDomain} | Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $DG.Alias -Emailaddresses @{remove=$_}`. Note that `EmailAddresses` items are in `type:address` format.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have an email address policy setting these already